# What is the reason for gfortran to discourage sind, cosd, tand functions?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The current **gfortran** (the GNU Fortran compiler version 13.1.0) recognizes the trigonometric functions **sind(x), cosd(x), tand(x), asind(x), acosd(x)** and **atand(x)**, which take arguments in degrees and produce angles in degrees, but at the same time it says that these functions are "*for compatibility only and should be avoided in favor of standard constructs wherever possible.*"

Could anyone explain why these functions should be avoided? Angles in degrees are more convenient in real life.

I don't know why these convenient functions should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You will find this warning at functions and subroutines that are *GNU extensions* in general. At least when their functionality can be implemented by standard means. GNU extensions are extensions to the standard set of intrinsic procedures, they are not present in the published Fortran standard. Often, they also appear in other compilers, not just in the GNU compiler, but they are not guaranteed to be available in all compilers.

As steve commented, these particular functions will actually be incorporated into the future Fortran standard and the warning will no longer be in place.

Comment: It should be noted that the degree trig functions have been added to the upcoming Fortran 2023 standard.  Eventually, gfortran will have a `-std=f2023` option and these will be promoted accordingly.  Finally, note that the argument reduction requires some care to obtain the desired accuracy.

Comment: @steve In that case you may want to remove the warning.

Comment: The warning will be removed.  I forgot to also mention that half-cycle trig functions (sinpi, cospi, etc) were also added to Fortran 2023.  Oh, and, Steve Lionel (J3 convenor) posted today that the most recent draft of F2023 has been forwarded for final approval.

Comment: @steve I have read one of the versions of Reid's "New in Fortran 2023" in the meantime. It is hard to keep track for an outsider as most of the discussion is about features that did not make it there (yet).